# Authorise a non Django User

Tags: python, django

I need to authorise a user on my Django powered site, but...

The user is not part of the Django user system (user table). However, I would it to behave like they have an active session just like they had logged like as a normal user.

Is this possible with Django, does Django support this sort of scenario?

I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction as I'm struggling to find information.

Comment: How do you know they are a valid user? Your Django site has to have some way of knowing which external users are valid, why not store them  as Django users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well how are you going to authenticate the user if they are not in Django user system?

If there is another table or some other way you want to authenticate a user, you can write a custom authentication backend and plug it in. See [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#authentication-backends) on this.

Comment: I have the other users in a table yes called external_users I would like to give them a logged in session just like a normal user has.

Comment: I see, so I can have Django check with the second backend using auth.backends cool

Comment: You can do that by creating a custom authentication backend. But I think you'll still need to map them to a django user though. For example, you may need to create a django user and return that user for every user in your other table. Or maybe you'll need to create a django user for each of your other users.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [django-lazysignup](https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup) does exactly what you are looking for.